# Delete the variations associated with attribute deleted

Tags: woocommerce

When I delete one attribute and save it does not delete the variations associated with that attribute.
I really would like to delete automatically the variations associated with the attributes that i have deleted.
My situation :
I have three values of the Ship from attribute, I want to keep only China .
But when I delete US and Europe that does not delete the others variations associated with US and Europe.
Any idea as to how I can do this for each product I want to change. Many thanks  https://ibb.co/G0cc1cL

Answer (score 0):

add this function to you functions.php file.

```
function kotsh_delete_variations_with_no_parent() {

    $variations = new WP_Query( array(
        'post_type' => 'product_variation',
        'posts_per_page' => -1
    ) );

    if ( $variations->have_posts() ) {

        while ( $variations->have_posts() ) {
            $variations->the_post();

            $parent = wp_get_post_parent_id( get_the_id() );

            if ( false === get_post_status( $parent ) ) {
                wp_delete_post( get_the_id(), true );
            }

        }

    }

    wp_reset_postdata();

}
add_action( 'init', 'kotsh_delete_variations_with_no_parent', 10 );
```

Comment: Thanks for replay;  I added this to function.php but no result, the variables are already there   :https://ibb.co/G0cc1cL

Comment: are you delete product!

Comment: i want delete attribute not product